# JSDoc object with keys being "one of" specific values and at least one required

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I want to write a function that takes in named arguments using an object. The object's keys are all optional, but at least one is required and they should be one of `"POST"`, `"GET"` and `"PUT"`.

```js
/**
 * Arguments for gqlValidate function.
 *
 * @typedef {object} GraphQLConfig
 * @property {string} schema - The GraphQL schema.
 * @property {string} rootType - Root type of the schema.
 *
 * A configuration for a route.
 * @typedef {object} RouteConfig
 * @property {GraphQLConfig} body - The required body params.
 * @property {GraphQLConfig} query - The required query params.
 * @property {Array.<{signer: string, properties: object, RequestParams: object}>} signatures - Array of signature params.
 * @property {Function} route - The route that should be called.
 */

/**
 *
 * @param {} routeConfigs - What do I need to put here?
 */
const createValidatedRoute = routeConfigs => {};
```

What do I need to put for `routeConfigs` so that it is an object where the keys are one of the above mentioned values and that at least one is required and that their value is a `RouteConfig`? The JSDocs didn't really help on this one. So a valid parameter would look like:

```js
export default createValidatedRoute = ({
  POST: {
    route,
    body: { schema, rootType },
    signatures: [{ signer: 'holder', properties, RequestParams }]
  }
});
```